# md-error is not firing with max/min for number input

Tags: angular, angular-material2

md-error is not firing for min/max in my input. It's working for 'required' though.

I imported MaterialModule in NgModule in app.module.ts.

**Html:**

```
<div class="form-group">
              <md-input-container>
                <input mdInput id="useramount"
                       name="useramount"
                       type="number"
                       class="form-control "
                       [(ngModel)]="amount"
                       #useramount="ngModel"
                       placeholder="amount"
                       min="{{40 | number}}"
                       max="{{300 | number}}"
                       required/>
                <md-error *ngIf="amountFormControl.hasError('required')">
                  <span>{{'NOT_VALID_FIELD'| translate}} </span>
                </md-error>
                <md-error *ngIf="amountFormControl.hasError('min')"
                    >
                  <span>{{'FIELD_MIN_VAL'| translate}}</span>
                </md-error>
                <md-error *ngIf="amountFormControl.hasError('max')"
                          >
                  <span>{{'FIELD_MAX_VAL'| translate}}</span>
                </md-error>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>
```

**ts file:**:

```
  public amountFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.min(40), Validators.required, Validators.max(300)]);
```

Comment: Not sure which version of material you're using, but MaterialModule 
 had been deprecated in beta 3. You need to import individual modules. In your case, you need to import MdInputModule. You can create your own module that imports and exports all the material modules you're going to use in your app and import that module in your app module.

Comment: @Rama using beta.8! it's working for me for required but i get min and max in the intellisense from Validators object! couldn't find any doc about them tho!! Is there any other option to do this validation on input type number?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `minlength` and `maxlength` instead of `min` and `max`.

That's how its document in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators).

> Angular forms include a number of built-in validator functions, which are functions that help you check common user input in forms. In addition to the built-in validators covered here of `minlength`, `maxlength`, and `required`, there are others such as `email` and `pattern` for Reactive Forms.